# How to know when Google Maps LiteMode map is loaded in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to load a Google Litemode map as the background for my Android app. My layout looks like this:

```
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/myMap"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:liteMode="true"
                app:mapType="satellite" />
```

In my Fragment my code is:

```
            mapView?.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
             googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(latitude, longitude), MainActivity.defaultCameraZoom))
                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener {
                    // Disables map clicks
                }
                mapViewHideItOverlay.visibility = View.GONE
            }
```

When my app runs the map defaults to showing the whole world. I'm hitting an API and getting a location and then running this code, which moves the camera to the correct location.  I like the idea of using this litemode view, because I only want the show the satellite view...but since litemode doesn't support any map event listeners I cannot figure out how to wait until the map is completely loaded BEFORE showing it in the UI.

So now I'm stuck with a UI that looks glitchy. The map shows the whole world for a split second and then jumps to where I want it to be targeting.

What am I missing? I was hoping litemode would support the animateCamera callback, but that's not supported either.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite#life_cycle_events . Check this out